# Error de cors en angular y asp.net web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, angular8

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, ya habia configurado cors desde el api y funcionaba bien todo de manera local. Ahora que subi el proyecto api a un servidor, ya accedo a el por una url distinta, y el error de cors volvio a aparecer.No se a que se deba, Ayuda porfa

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Saludos Alondra, al margen de los enlaces que te comenta el buen @RogerTorné, te invito a leer los ingredientes de una buena pregunta en: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Te ayudará mucho